# Rollback to 120.0.2210.144

Tags: package, fixed, rollback, expand, webview2

Microsoft WebView2 version 121.0.2277.83 being withdrawn due to reported issues. I am attempting to roll back to the previous version, specifically 120.0.2210.144.

I downloaded the fixed version 120.0.2210.144 from Microsoft. There instructions say avoid decompressing through file explorer because it might not generate the correct folder. So I want to know what destination should I try to decompress it.